# Can a cocos-2dx project be wrapped into a standard Java app so ndk is not required?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I have a cocos2d-x project finished, for an Android app. I have a standard java Android app to begin with, then open the Cocos2d-x code/activity after ~2 java activities/menu screens used. With the cocos2d-x code complete, can I wrap the cocos2d-x code in a way that I can just run the app like a standard (non-ndk) activity? I know this NDK/C type code would be made un-editable.

PS: A programmer made the cocos2d-x code a while back now in Eclipse, and I want to move it over to AS also as part of this update

Answer (score 0):

**No.** Cocos2d-x runs in an OpenGL frame and it needs NDK to communicate with java and java to cocos2d-x.

If you want to use Android Studio upgrade to the latest Cocos2d-x version because it has an AS template.